# Python Selenium Element is not clickable

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to gather the information on a website using Python 3.6 and Selenium, however, the page loads right away on Chrome(54.0.2840.87(64-bit)), it goes to the tab(Case Logs) for half second, then it changes to another tab(Alerts).

I tried to find it using 'find_element_by', clicking at certain point, finding the text on the tab(Case Logs). If I use 'find_element_by_xpath', I get 'Element is not clickable at point (488, 93). Other element would receive the click'.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


#enter credentials
user = input('User: ')
password = input('Password: ')
case = input('Case: ')

#open the page
driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('.com')

#login
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("user")
elem.send_keys(user)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
elem.send_keys(password)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#Find Case
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("searchCaseIdHome")
elem.send_keys(case)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#Find Notes
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen151']")
elem.click()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIG7V.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUmTN.png

Comment: Can you share the url ? Which element do you want to click ? Please tell us what actions you want to do on the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the tool I use at work place, reason why I cannot share the URL, however, I need web driver to click(or find the text by doing ctrl + f in order to click) on Case Logs(please check the picture attached).

Comment: the reason for the error is nonunqiue xpath....Can you please add some extra html of the page

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUmTN.png

Answer (score -1):

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ext-gen151']")
elem.location_once_scrolled_into_view
elem.click()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (864, 94). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ext-el-mask" id="ext-gen338"></div>